# Create a dynamic list where the content of multiple files are the elements

Tags: ansible

I have a problem where I need to read the content of a directory and create a list where every item is the content of a yaml file in that directory.

The directory structure is like this

```
/vars/
      abc.yml
      def.yml
      ...
      xyz.yml
```

The content of each file is similar to this

```
---
manufacturer: F5
model: BIG-IP 3900
slug: big-ip-3900
part_number: '3900'
u_height: 1
is_full_depth: true
```

my task looks like this

```
---
- name: Include device types of .yaml files in directory into the 'device_types' variable
  include_vars:
    dir: vars/
    ignore_unknown_extensions: True
    extensions:
      - "yaml"
      - "yml"
    name: device_types

- name: Create NetBox Device Types
  netbox.netbox.netbox_device_type:
    netbox_token: "{{ netbox_token }}"
    netbox_url: "{{ netbox_url }}"
    validate_certs: False
    data:
      model: "{{ item.model }}"
      slug: "{{ item.slug }}"
      part_number: "{{ item.part_number }}"
      manufacturer: "{{ item.manufacturer | default(omit) }}"
      u_height: "{{ item.u_height | default(omit) }}"
      is_full_depth: "{{ item.is_full_depth | default(False)}}"
      subdevice_role: "{{ item.subdevice_role | default(omit) }}"
      comments: "{{ item.comments  | default(omit) }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ device_types }}"
  when: device_types is defined
  run_once: yes
  tags: netbox_device_types
```

But when I then try to loop thru the device_types variable it just loops thru the elments of the content of each file.
I cannot change the format of the files, so I have to change the import to make the data fit.

```
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {'manufacturer': 'Palo Alto', 'model': 'PA-850', 'slug': 'pa-850', 'part_number': 'PA-850', 'ight': 1, 'is_full_depth': False, 'interfaces': [{'name': 'management', 'type': '1000base-t', 'mgmt_only': True}, {'name': 'dedicated-ha1', 'type': '1000base-t'}, {'name': 'dedicated-ha2', 'type': '1000-t'}, {'name': 'loopback', 'type': 'virtual'}, {'name': 'ethernet1/1', 'type': '1000base-t'}, {'name': 'ethernet1/2', 'type': '1000base-t'}, {'name': 'ethernet1/3', 'type': '1000base-t'},..
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of a current loop with debugging, the actual result you are getting and what you expect instead ? (I personally did not understand what the problem is...)

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: Your error message is telling you that you try to loop over a dict where a list is expected (you can transforma a dict to a list but that will not help here...). Moreover, each file you include contains the exact same dictionary keys so they all override the previous include leaving you only with the last included file values. In other words, this can't work. See @vladimirs's answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the files with the minimized content for testing

```sh
shell> tree test_vars
test_vars/
├── abc.yml
├── def.yml
└── xyz.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat test_vars/abc.yml 
---
manufacturer: F5
model: BIG-IP 3900
```

```yaml
shell> cat test_vars/def.yml
---
manufacturer: F5
model: BIG-IP 3901
```

```yaml
shell> cat test_vars/xyz.yml
---
manufacturer: F5
model: BIG-IP 3902
```

Find the files

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: test_vars
        patterns: '*.yml,*.yaml'
      register: result
```

gives

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - test_vars/xyz.yml
  - test_vars/abc.yml
  - test_vars/def.yml
```

Then create the file with the task to include one file and add the item to a list, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat include_device_type.yml
- include_vars:
    file: "{{ item }}"
    name: device_type
- set_fact:
    device_types: "{{ device_types|d([]) + [device_type] }}"
```

Iterate the files and include the data in the list

```yaml
    - include_tasks: include_device_type.yml
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives the list of the device types

```yaml
  device_types:
  - manufacturer: F5
    model: BIG-IP 3902
  - manufacturer: F5
    model: BIG-IP 3900
  - manufacturer: F5
    model: BIG-IP 3901
```